# JavaScript method not execute 'style.display=none'

Tags: javascript

I've an embedded app. This app is written in JSP. There is a `js` file with the following code:

```
function openScanning() {
    document.getElementById('divModalScanning').style.display = 'block';
    startScan();
}
```

When I click the button, and call this method, the modal is not showing.

However, if I comment the line "startScan()", the modal is showing.

```
function openScanning() {
    document.getElementById('divModalScanning').style.display = 'block';
    //startScan();
}
```

I have no idea why this happens.
Can someone explain it to me?

I try to change to style.visibility = 'visible', but not effect.

As requested, follow the codo of "startScan()":

```
function startScan() {  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/service/servlet/startScan.do', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('tipo', tipoAtual);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('resolucao', resolucaoAtual);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('densidade', densidadeAtual);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('rotacionar', orientacaoAtual);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('tamanho', tamanhoAtual);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('duplex', duplexAtual);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        var ready = xhr.readyState;
        if (ready == 4) {
            document.getElementById('divModalScanning').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('divModalScanNext').style.visibility = 'visible';
            var httpStatus = xhr.status;
            if (httpStatus == 200) {
            } else {
                showError(xhr.statusText, function() { document.getElementById('divModalError').style.visibility = 'hidden'; voltar(); });
            }
        }           
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e) { };
    xhr.send();
}
```

The line "document.getElementById('divModalScanNext').style.visibility = 'visible';" is executed normaly

Comment: What does `startScan` do?

Comment: Perhaps `startScan()` sets `.style.display = 'none'`?  eg when it finishes scanning.  If `startScan` is *not* asynchronous then the display will only be updated when it has finished - so you'll never see it if it's hidden at the end of the process.  Remember, js is single-threaded and that includes updating the UI.

Comment: You could (should) make `startScan` asynchronous (if it's not already) or add `setTimeout(startScan, 1)` so that the browser has time to update the UI.  If `startScan` takes more than a few ms, then it will still block the browser (if not async, which it appears not to be) until it complete.  (there are other options such as `requestAnimationFrame`), but we should know what the cause is before going down that route.  ie:  *What does `startScan` do?*  (as per comment above)

Comment: You're setting async to false *which is deprecated*. That's precisely your problem here - the sync request blocks the UI thread, therefore the `display = 'none'` doesn't update the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing `false` as the [third parameter to XMLHttpRequest.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#parameters), you're doing a synchronous, blocking HTTP request. JavaScript is single-threaded (unless you're workers or similar), so your tab won't be able to do *anything* (including updating the page to reflect your `style.display` change) until the call finishes.

Synchronous HTTP requests really aren't recommended for this reason - you can't control the network, and you don't want to make the page unresponsive if the network is slower than you think.